# How to write a test to resource which uses JSON body as params in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, testing, jackson

Like in the topic, does anyone know how to do it? I didn't see any API or tutorial how to do it. My sample resource:

```
@Path("/tests")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class TestResource {
    private final SomeDAO dao;
    public TestResource(SomeDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public static class RequestBody {
        @JsonProperty("p1")
        public String p1;

        @JsonProperty("p2")
        public String p2;
    }
    @POST
    @UnitOfWork
    public Saying postSomething(RequestBody requestBody) {
        Thing thing = dao.create(new Thing(requestBody.p1, requestBody.p2));
        return new Saying("Added : " + actor.toString());
        //Saying is the representation of JSON response
    }
```

Comment: issue an HTTP POST and examine result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache CXF's & Jersey's test utilities for writing end to end test cases for JAX-RS resources. See the sample on link below:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAXRS+Testing
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html

Comment: But is there a way to do it with jersey testing?

Comment: Updated the answer to include jersey unit testing resources as well.